# Why is my for loop an illegal declaration

Tags: perl, for-loop

I created two subs one to do Fibonacci and the other to test even numbers. When I call it though it is saying my for loop in line 7 the sub Fibonacci is illegal why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my ($x,$y);
my $num = 0;

sub Fibs($start,$stop){
    for ($start..$stop){
        ($x, $y) = ($y, $x+$y);
            my $total += $y;
        }
    print "$total \n"
}

sub even($num){
    if ($num % 2 == 0){
        return $num;}
}

my $big_total = Fibs(even($num), 3999999)
```

Edited from suggestions below.

Clearly I am missing something. From feedback updated to new version.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my ($x,$y);
my $num = 0;

sub Fibs{
    my ($start, $stop) = @_ ;
    for ($start..$stop){
        my ($x, $y) = (0,2);
            if ($x % 2 == 0){
                ($x, $y) = ($y, $x+$y);
                    my $total += $y;
        }
}

my $big_total = Fibs(0, 3999999)
```

Comment: By default, Perl processes arguments from a stack like shell does. If you want Algol-style function signatures, you need extra software: any of [Method::Signatures](http://p3rl.org/Method::Signatures), [Method::Signatures::Simple](http://p3rl.org/Method::Signatures::Simple), [MooseX::Method::Signatures](http://p3rl.org/MooseX::Method::Signatures), [perl5i](http://p3rl.org/perl5i), [signatures](http://p3rl.org/signatures). [Learn the language](http://learn.perl.org) properly instead of muddling through with carrying over assumptions from other ones.

Comment: @daxim sorry for learning. I will be brilliant right away next time.

Comment: Now you're missing a `}`.  That might have been clearer if your indentation were more consistent.  What is your question about this new program?  If you get an error message, you should show us the exact message, not just hint that perl says that it's illegal.

Comment: That's a flamebait if I've ever seen one. Show evidence that you're actually learning in a structure fashion and not just whacking at source code until it works. - Every single Perl learning material I've seen teaches to get the function parameters from `@_`.

Comment: actually have consulted literature and a video course. Here http://www.udemy.com/beginner-perl-maven/ and http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/ . Have I made mistakes yes. Hope you are all perfect and never make mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the missing opening braces, Perl doesn't support that kind of declaration for subroutine parameters.

Rather than

```
sub Fibs($start, $stop) {
    ...
}
```

you need to write something like:

```
sub Fibs {
    my($start, $stop) = @_;
    ...
}
```

(Perl does have prototypes, but they're not really intended for declaring the types of parameters, and they don't provide names.  See [this article](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1406) for a discussion.)

Other problems:

You should add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You never use the `$x` and `$y` that you declare in the outer scope.

Your `even` function appears to be incomplete.  It doesn't (explicitly) return a value if its argument is an odd number.  What exactly is it intended to do?

Comment: it is only supposed to test if a number is even and return it if it is.

Comment: @sayth: If the number is even, it just returns the number.  What should it do if the number is odd?

Comment: if it is odd I want it too not use it. seems that function may be useless so just incorperated it into fibs sub.

Comment: @sayth: If the function is supposed to tell you whether the number is even, then it needs to return a true value if it's even, and a false value if it's odd.  For example: `sub even { my($x) = @_; if ($x % 2 == 0) { return 1; } else { return 0; } }`.  (That could be more concise, but I wanted to emphasize the point that you need to return a value in either case.)

Comment: Thank You for taking your time to explain it.